# SQL Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 :Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to using SQL Server and I face a problem which appear this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

As you can view in this screenshot

[image]

Thanks

Comment: ***ALWAYS*** first consult *the one truth about SQL Server* - the [SQL Server Books Online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) to verify your syntax and options ....

Comment: Thanks , I will consult it in the next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the `;`. This char marks the end of statement which is wrong in this case.
Also you could add this char at the end of `CREATE DATABASE` statement thus:

```
CREATE DATABASE ... /*;*/ ON ......... aa.mdf');
                      ^                        ^
 delete (mandatory) --|    insert (optional) --|
```